# Mega Nav works fine with any browser except for IE8 below.

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, nav, megamenu

This is the site I'm current working on.

http://mdnetsolutions.com/

The dropdown menu works fine with any browsers except for IE8 and below.
I have tried adding htmlshiv and other types of fixes I could find here but still no luck.

Is the Mega nav jquery not loading on IE8?.

http://codecanyon.net/item/shifty-nav-a-fully-responsive-js-css3-mega-menu/full_screen_preview/5319528

^ This is the Nav we are currently using, but I checked this one in IE8 and it's working just fine.

For anyone who could give me a hint on the problem we would really appreciate it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

David, 
The component you are using does not support IE8. Please double-check. Here's a screenshot of how it looks when I change the document mode to IE8.

[image]

#### Edit

Try setting this in your meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

This will instruct ie to render in IE8

Comment: Ohhhhh, I changed them both to IE8 both Browser mode and Document mode and it worked, didn't know I have to do it this way. Any idea or suggestions how I would fix this prob?

Comment: Hi, Shifty Nav works when it is set to this http://imgur.com/XU7RAXq 
Not sure why it doesn't work our side @_@. The code you gave above didn't fix it :(.